# parsing tree from csv

Tags: python, parsing

How can I simply parsing the tree from file?
Actually I am only able to get the 'nodes'

```
with open('source.txt') as f:
    lines = f.read().splitlines()

for line in lines:
    if line.startswith("+"):
        print(line)
```

input:

```
+- Y
|  +- Y1
|  +- Y9
|  +- Y10
|  |  +- Y101
|  |  \- Y81
|  \- Y11
|     +- Y111
|     |  +- Y1111
|     |  \- Y1112
|     +- Y112
|     +- Y113
|        \- Y1131
+- Z
|  +- Z1
|  |  +- Z11
|  |  +- Z14
|  |  \- Z15
|  +- Z2
|  |  \- Z21
|  |     \- Z211
|  |        +- Z2111
|  |        \- Z2112
|  \- Z3
```

output should be:

X,Y,Y1;Y9;Y10;Y101;Y81;Y11;Y111;Y1111;Y1112;Y112;Y113;Y1131

X,Z,Z1;Z11;Z14;Z15;Z2;Z21;Z211;Z2111;Z2112;Z3

Input:

Comment: _I am only able to get the 'nodes'_ I assume you mean `X, Y, and Z`. That's because of `if line.startswith("+"):`. You can delete that.

Comment: yes, I am getting X, Y, Z. but need to have all records related to node in one line

Answer (score 0):

It's not parsing actually. You are just rewriting names in each line.
This code may be helpful:

```
import re

print('X,Y,' + ';'.join(re.findall(r'Y.+',s)))
print('X,Z,' + ';'.join(re.findall(r'Z.+',s)))
```

Comment: Note that in your input file I did't see X, so I hard coded that. But you can easily change to be like whatever you want. Glad to help if you ask.